# If $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$ prove that $\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta) + \sin(2\gamma) = 4\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$ prove that $\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta) + \sin(2\gamma) = 4\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)$

I am really confused of how to utilize the information given. 

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with:
$$\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta)=2\sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)=2\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha-\beta)$$

Then
$$\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta)+\sin(2\gamma)=2\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha-\beta)+\sin(2\gamma)$$

$$\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta)+\sin(2\gamma)=2\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha-\beta)+2\sin(\gamma)\cos(\gamma)=$$
$$=2\sin(\gamma)(\cos(\alpha-\beta)+\cos(\gamma))=4\sin(\gamma)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta+\gamma}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are very welcome!